# Angular 6: Check availability of hosts/servers

Tags: javascript, angular, availability

I have done a lot of research, but there was no real success.

I'm looking for a way to check reachability/availability of hosts with angular? E.g. I want to check if the authentication backend is available? The only way I found so far is by using the HttpClient to open a connection and check if an error occurs?

Are there any other/better ways of accomplishing such a task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to your words, I am considering availability check = HTTP Request status 200 or 404. There is no other way except HttpClient. The only connection bridge between frontend and backend is the HTTP communication

Comment: Agree with Debojyoti, only way to check availability is trying to contact it. You may want to reduce the timeout on the XHR object to have a faster fail if the server is not responding (like `xhr.timeout = 1000;`) during your availability check. Also, make sure you are not checking a resource that has some HTTP caching applied -- that would give you false positives.

Comment: You can connect to the back end with a web socket. Is it a a better alternative? Probably not, but it really depends on your requirements.

Comment: The best option would be on "APP_INITIALIZATION" to run a ping to the server and see if you get a 200 success request or 503/504 (dont remember which one) as fail request and then having like a global variable "backendAvailable" true/false

Comment: i've got many connections to different backends (signalr, rest, some websockets) and i want to test, if those machines are available. 
But if there is no other way, i'm going to use a HttpClient test connections.
thanks a lot!